# asp.net authentication mode="Forms" timeout not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, form-authentication

I strucked with this problem for past 2 days. My MVC project is using the form authentication. I set the timeout as 1 min (just for testing). It sucessfully get timeout. Because after one minute pages not working. But i need to redirect to my login page. I gave login url in form authentication. But it won't works. Any body please suggest me the solution for this problem. The code as follows

```
<authentication mode="Forms">

<forms loginUrl="~/Login/Login" path="/" timeout="1" protection="All" />

</authentication>
```

The error shows in the following code when get timeout. By this error only i found that the timeout will be occur successfully but the redirection is only in a problem.

```
public ActionResult Employee()
        {



            mod.StateDetails = objentity.ExecuteFunction<GetStateDetails_Result>("GetStateDetails").ToList();
            List<ObjectParameter> lstParam = new List<ObjectParameter>();
            int Divsion = Convert.ToInt32(logmodel.getDivisionId().ToString());
            ObjectParameter objparam5 = new ObjectParameter("Division", Divsion);
            lstParam.Add(objparam5);
            mod.custinfo = objentity.ExecuteFunction<GetCustomerInfoByDivision_Result>("GetCustomerInfoByDivision", lstParam.ToArray()).ToList();
            mod.SkillInfo = objentity.ExecuteFunction<GetSkillInfo_Result>("GetSkillInfo").ToList();
            mod.DivisionDetails = objentity.ExecuteFunction<GetDivisionDetails_Result>("GetDivisionDetails").ToList();
            int roleid = Convert.ToInt32(logmodel.getRoleId().ToString());
            mod.RoleId = roleid;
            return View(mod);
        }
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you sure your loginUrl is ~/Login/Login rather than ~/Account/Login?

Comment: What happens when the authentication cookie expires? Aren't you redirected to the LogOn page?

Comment: @Jeow Li Huan: I am sure about my URL.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov It Shows error like "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." in the code.

Comment: In which code? Did you decorate your controller actions with the `[Authorize]` attribute?

Comment: No i am not designed with such a attribute. The error shows in this line "int Divsion = Convert.ToInt32(logmodel.getDivisionId().ToString());"

Comment: @ArunKumarT post the code where the exception is happening not just a single line and give more details

Comment: @ Darin Dimtrov: By this error only i confirm that the timeout is working..

Comment: Yes, you have confirmed. It is working. So what is your question? It is the Authorize attribute that performs the redirect to the LogIn action if the authentication cookie has expired. So if you want this redirect to happen you will have to decorate your controller action with it.

Comment: @Mark Now i posted my code which i got error. This is due to when i clicked employee tab in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to decorate your controller action with the `[Authorize]` attribute if you want the user to be redirected when accessing a controller action that requires authentication:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Employee()
{
    mod.StateDetails = objentity.ExecuteFunction<GetStateDetails_Result>("GetStateDetails").ToList();
    List<ObjectParameter> lstParam = new List<ObjectParameter>();
    int Divsion = Convert.ToInt32(logmodel.getDivisionId().ToString());
    ObjectParameter objparam5 = new ObjectParameter("Division", Divsion);
    lstParam.Add(objparam5);
    mod.custinfo = objentity.ExecuteFunction<GetCustomerInfoByDivision_Result>("GetCustomerInfoByDivision", lstParam.ToArray()).ToList();
    mod.SkillInfo = objentity.ExecuteFunction<GetSkillInfo_Result>("GetSkillInfo").ToList();
    mod.DivisionDetails = objentity.ExecuteFunction<GetDivisionDetails_Result>("GetDivisionDetails").ToList();
    int roleid = Convert.ToInt32(logmodel.getRoleId().ToString());
    mod.RoleId = roleid;
    return View(mod);
}
```

The Authorize attribute will verify if the user supplied a valid authentication cookie and if not redirect him to the Login page that you specified in your web.config file.